# npm protobuf fails

Tags: node.js, npm, protocol-buffers

I am using windows 7, and get this error when doing

```
    npm install protobuf




D:\Projects\EventstoreSample\node_modules\protobuf>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs
\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed:   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import platform; print platform.python_version();
gyp ERR! stack                                   ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:540:15)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:638:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:680:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Projects\EventstoreSample\node_modules\protobuf
```

My pythonpath variable in environment variables, is set to :

```
"C:\Python33\Lib;C:\Python33\DLLs;"
```

On typing python in my command prompt takes me to python shell.

How do I fix this issue?

PS : I have never used python. Installed it because of this dependency.

Comment: Try installing Python 2.7 instead. The Node build scripts are not compatible with Python 3.

Comment: @robertklep Post this as the answer so you can get credit.